# htaccess for fully ajax based site

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I am making fully ajax based site. Whenever any URL hit for site, I need to load common view. So for that I made this in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

And after loading common view, I am making an ajax call but because of this htaccess, ajax call again loading same view.

For example,

If anyone is requesting for `www.abc.com/dashboard`, it needs to load `index.php` file first. And then I will be another making request for `/dashboard`to get the HTML content.

In short, index.php loads the skeleton, and then I am ready to load the data from ajax.
But because of the above htaccess, it will load `index.php` even if i will request to `/dashboard`.

I am in deadlock.

More information:
I am using `jQuery` and `asual address` plugin for handing change event of address.

I am using `CodeIgniter`.

Comment: I bet that the problem is in your jquery ajax request (which you're not showing) or maybe you left out the `base tag` in your html header.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to your htaccess. You should have logic in index.php file, which would route AJAX requests differently than normal requests.

Comment: You can do that exactly. Check http://www.slideshare.net/samsonasik/codeigniter-custom-routing-manipulate-uri

Answer (score 0):

try

```
include_once('/dashboard/mydashboard.php');
```

in your index.php
and then run the logic of mydashboard.php (or however you will call it)

Comment: but i am using CodeIgniter.

Comment: I don't know about codeIgniter but it should be possible as edvinas.me pointed out. If codeIgniter is too complex for you try an easier/simpler CMS